# Access JSON object key/value where value is an array using underscorejs

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have a local JSON dataset (outlined below) and am trying to use the `_.where` method to retrieve specific values from within the dataset.

**JSON File**

```
"data": [{
    "singles_ranking": [116],
    "matches_lost": ["90"],
    "singles_high_rank": [79],
    "matches_won": ["170"],
    "singles_ranking/_source": ["116"],
    "year_matches_won": ["11"],
    "name": ["Pfizenmaier Dinah"],
    "gender": ["woman"],
    "_resultNumber": 1,
  },{etc},{etc}];
```

Currently I am trying to retrieve values from within the dataset like so:

```
var mappedPlayers = _.map(players,function(key,val){return key});
var filteredPlayers = _.where(mappedPlayers, {name:'Pfizenmaier Dinah'}); 
console.log(filteredPlayers);
```

This currently returns `undefined`. I am 90% sure that this is because the key values are stored within an array however, I am not sure how I can modify this `_.where` condition to actually make it return the text within the `value` attribute.

Any help would be greatly welcomed. Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `._where` it is not possible, but you can use [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter), like so

```
var where = {key: 'name', value: 'Pfizenmaier Dinah'};
var filteredPlayers = _.filter(players, function (el) {
    // check if key exists in Object, check is value is Array, check if  where.value exists  in Array  
    return el[where.key] && _.isArray(el[where.key]) && _.indexOf(el[where.key], where.value) >= 0;
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/bvnr0vw9/)